# How to prevent cyclic dependencyd when creating signed cert for EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm using [terraform](https://www.terraform.io) to create an EC2 instance which will be used as a docker host. This means I need to create encryption keys to securely connect to it over the internet. When creating the keys you need to specify the IP address and hostnames you will be connecting with. In terraform these values can be dynamically allocated, but this easily results in a cyclic dependency situation. Lets use an example:

```
resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "ECDSA"
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "docker_host_key" {
  key_algorithm = "${tls_private_key.example.algorithm}"
  private_key_pem = "${tls_private_key.example.private_key_pem}"
  validity_period_hours = 12
  early_renewal_hours = 3
  allowed_uses = ["server_auth"]
  dns_names = [ "${aws_instance.example.public_dns}" ]
  ip_addresses = [ "${aws_instance.example.public_ip}" ]
  subject {
    common_name = "example.com"
    organization = "example"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 1
  ami = "ami-d05e75b8"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "subnet-24h4fos9"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo \"${tls_self_signed_cert.docker_host_key.private_key_pem}\" > private_key_pem",
      "echo \"${tls_self_signed_cert.docker_host_key.cert_pem}\" > cert_pem",
      "echo \"${tls_private_key.docker_host_key.private_key_pem}\" > private_key_pem2",
    ]
  }
}
```

In the `remote-exec` provisioner we need to write values from the `tls_self_signed_cert` resource, which in turn needs values from the `aws_instance` resource.

How can I overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`aws_eip`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip.html) resource to create an Elastic IP and attach it to the instance with `aws_eip_association`.

```
resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
  ...
}

resource "aws_eip_association" "eip" {
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.eip.id}"
  instance_id = "${aws_instance.example.id}"
}

resource "tls_self_signed_cert" "docker_host_key" {
  # set something here from Route53 instead: dns_names = [ "${aws_instance.example.public_dns}" ]
  ip_addresses = [ "${aws_eip.eip.public_ip}" ]
  ...
}
```